# Conversion failed when converting SMALLDATETIME values stored as VARCHAR to DATE

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a table with millions of records and one of the columns (Hit_DateTime) is set as VARCHAR datatype but the values the column hold are all in SMALLDATETIME (Sample 2023-04-26 20:57:00), I'm trying to split the date part alone from this column and doing an **INSERT** into another table using **SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(Hit_DateTime,0,10) As DATE)** but for some reason it keeps failing for the error -> **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

I have tried multiple ways to fix this issue but unfortunately, nothing works. And also I can't find any issues with the data I have got. PFA the sample values I currently have in my table for the mentioned column.

```
Hit_DateTime
2022-12-01 00:04:00
2022-12-01 00:13:00
2022-12-01 00:25:00
2022-12-01 00:26:00
2022-12-01 00:41:00
2022-12-01 00:47:00
2022-12-01 00:50:00
2022-12-01 00:52:00
2022-12-01 01:03:00
2022-12-01 01:14:00
2022-12-01 01:22:00
2022-12-01 01:24:00
2022-12-01 01:25:00
2022-12-01 01:28:00
2022-12-01 01:37:00
2022-12-01 01:48:00
2022-12-01 01:49:00
2022-12-01 02:00:00
2022-12-01 02:12:00
2022-12-01 02:14:00
2022-12-01 02:15:00
2022-12-01 02:18:00
2022-12-01 02:26:00
2022-12-01 02:27:00
2022-12-01 02:37:00
2022-12-01 02:51:00
2022-12-01 02:53:00
2022-12-01 03:17:00
2022-12-01 03:19:00
```

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue in my enviromnet by creating table and inserting sample values into that.

```
CREATE  TABLE [dbo].[Data]
(
    ID int  NOT  NULL,
    Name varchar(30),
    Hit_DateTime DATETIME
)
insert  into  Data  values(1,'AA','2022-12-01 00:04:00')
insert  into  Data  values(2,'BB','2022-12-01 00:13:00')
insert  into  Data  values(3,'CC','2022-12-01 00:25:00')
insert  into  Data  values(4,'DD','2022-12-01 00:26:00')
insert  into  Data  values(5,'EE','2022-12-01 00:41:00')
insert  into  Data  values(6,'FF','2022-12-01 00:47:00')
insert  into  Data  values(7,'GG','2022-12-01 00:50:00')
insert  into  Data  values(8,'HH','2022-12-01 00:52:00')
```

I tried retrieve only date from Hit_Date column using below code:

```
SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Hit_DateTime, 120), 0, 10) AS  DATE)FROM [data];
```

I got below error:

[image]

I tried with below code:

```
SELECT  LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Hit_DateTime, 120), 10) as  DATE  FROM [data];
```

I was able to retrieve only date from Hit_DateTime column:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhavani, The output should be of datatype - DATE, your query generates the output in VARCHAR. This isn't my requirement, also my further requirement is to INSERT the SELECT output to a table, this is where I get the error.